# Disable Password for Preview Testing on Nitrous.IO

Tags: nitrousio

How can I disable the username and password for preview testing? Even if I set both box-username and box-password to null, anyone who tries to view the preview link will be prompted with a box asking for a username and password.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this still happening for you? This may be an issue on Nitrous' end if so. Contact their support team at support@nitrous.io with your box number for further help.